# Is there an alternative to temporary tables I can use on a Hot Standby copy?

Tags: postgresql, temp-tables

as suggested here's a TL;DR bit. I'm looking for an alternative to temporary tables I could use on a Hot Standby copy of a database. Is there anything or do I have to re-write everything and try and do it all in subqueries?

When I joined our company last year, our ERP was hosted locally and although I didn’t have admin access to the Postgres database I at least had read write access to the tables.

I wrote a number of reports (using SQL Command option in Crystal Reports)/SQL scripts that use temporary tables however, we’ve just migrated to a hosted version of the ERP and rather than access the live database we have been given access to a Hot Standby copy, mainly due to load balancing issues.

Unfortunately, the software company didn’t warn us that this would be the case or that it would be read only access. I found this out when I was testing some scripts when obviously anything with a temporary table failed.

I use temporary tables for things like storing dates and bank holiday information, holding temporary calculations and so on.

So I'm looking for an alternative to temporary tables I could use on the Hot Standby copy, or do I have to re-write everything and try and do it all in subqueries?

I’ve looked at using CTE (WITH) but the scope is far too small as I’d need access throughout the script.

Then I thought maybe I could read the data from the Hot Standby but create temporary tables in a different database/schema, but I don’t think that’s viable. If it is I might have to speak to the software house to be given access to another database/schema. postgres_fdw would seem the most likely candidate as you can update the external table but I can't see anywhere about dropping and creating tables.

I’ve only been using Postgres since last July having previously used MSSQL which I could probably have used a table variable, but I can’t find an equivalent for that.

I've tried looking at the Postgres documentation but, to some embarrassment, I do find a lot of documentation hard to follow without relatable examples, so I might well have missed something.

Sorry for the long post!

Thanks

Comment: Hello! it would be useful to add a TLDR with just what you need.

Comment: It is pretty clear what OP needs. You can't get that on a standby server, and there is no substitute I can think of. Move the application back to the primary.

Comment: Hi, @AguV i've added a TLDR to the question.

Comment: Hi @LaurenzAlbe Thanks, I suspected as much but hoped there was something.

Comment: I am always a bit suspicious if people use temporary tables all over the place - especially when coming from SQL Server where they are very often used to work around the obnoxious (default) locking behaviour.  Are you sure you need all those temp tables? If you use them for lookups, why not store that data in regular tables?

Comment: Not sure what you actually use them for, but  the closest thing to a "table variable" in Postgres would be an array from a composite type - that can be used nearly like a table. But a variable requires a function (or procedure) and you can't create a function on a standby either.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Hi, Unfortunately I can't create tables otherwise I would store lookup data in there. 
It's probably not the most efficient way of doing things but I kind of use them like a view, combining data from different tables and then performing different calculations on that table. Then if i need that in a few locations in the report it's easier (for me at least) to reference the temporary table then to repeat subqueries. 
I'm still learning and know i've got a lot to learn about Postgres and SQL in general so I appreciate all feedback. Thanks :)

Comment: Oh and the other thing I use temp tables for are to replicate the use of parameters, for example, start and end dates or a sales rep code as these could be used multiple times in the script. Again, there may be a better way in Postgres to do this